# Help understanding the compactness of $[0, 1]$.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

After doing some homework for my Topology course, I am confused about why this reasoning doesn't show that $[0,1]$ is not compact in $\mathbb{R}$. Clearly this isn't true, so where is the flaw?

**Answer:** The problem is that $[0,1]-K \neq \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \left(\dfrac{1}{n+1},\dfrac{1}{n}\right)$ because $0 \in [0, 1] - K$.

Note that $K = \{\frac{1}{n} | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ isn't compact because it doesn't have a least element. Additionally, note that $K$ is closed in $[0,1]$ as

$$[0,1] - K = \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \left(\dfrac{1}{n+1},\dfrac{1}{n}\right).$$

Since $K$, a subspace of $[0,1]$, is closed and not compact, $[0, 1]$ cannot be compact in $\mathbb{R}$.

**Note:** However, does this reasoning work in $\mathbb{R}_k$? What about in $\mathbb{R}_l$?

Comment: $S:=[0,1]\setminus K$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$ since the point $1\in [0,1]$ is a limit point and not in $S$. In fact really all of the $1/n$’s are limit points that arent in $S$.

Comment: $[0,1] - K$ is not closed in $\mathbb R$. And in addition to the union of open intervals it contains $0$. By the way, the intervals are $\left(\dfrac{1}{n+1},\dfrac{1}{n}\right)$.

Comment: $[0,1]- K$ is closed in $\mathbb R$ as the union of open sets".  As the union of open sets *what*?  That seems to be a sentence fragment.  What *about* $\cup_{i\text{(sic)}\in N} (\frac 1n, \frac 1{n+1})$?  What are you trying to say?

Comment: Are you saying $[0,1]- K$ *is equal* to $\cup (\frac 1n, \frac 1{n+1})$?  If so (it isn't quite--- it's $\{0\}\cup (\cup (\frac 1{n+1},\frac 1n)$) wouldn't that mean $[0,1]-K$ is *open*?  As it is the union of *open* sets?

Comment: $K$ is not a closed subspace of $[0,1]$. Its closure is $K \cup \{0\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$[0,1]\setminus K$ is the the union you wrote. Note that $0 \in [0,1]\setminus K$ but $0$ is not in the union.

Comment: I think you mean "is *not*."